# How to print to printer in java

Tags: java, netbeans, printing

How would I print a simple paragraph on a piece of paper the same way System.out.println("words") would work? Using a printwriter to put it in a .txt file and printing from there would also be a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate? [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("The first line");
writer.println("The second line");
writer.close();
```

Comment: this is something entirely different. It doesn't print through a printer, for instance.